# How to manage multiple STOP-LIST for a single database? Where each STOP-LIST is created for a specific query result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using **MS-SQL Server 2008**, where I have created two different custom stop-list for my database. Now both the stop-list contains different stop-words. My aim is to use each of the stop-list for a specific fulltext query search result.

**For example:** There is a Job portal where Candidates are searching for the Jobs with some keywords, whereas Employers are searching for the right Candidates with some keywords. Now consider that there are two different stop-list that I would like to manage, one Stop-List for Job Search specific and another stop-list is for Candidate Search specific.

How can I achieve this in my SQL Query or Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much FTS experience but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) states that stop lists are applied via full-text indexes, and only one full-text index per table or view is allowed. So applying stop lists dynamically in queries is obviously not possible.

What would be possible on the other hand is to create an indexed view on your table. Then you could put one full-text index on the table and a second one on the view, each with a different stop list. You would have to modify the queries too, of course, so that job searches use the table and candidate searches use the view (or vice versa).

If that approach doesn't work for you, then you would have to look into [alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Software) that have the functionality you need.